# Automating an installation using BAT/PS scripts

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, automation, wix

I have been attempting to automate the installation of one of my applications but have run into a few roadblocks and I really need some help.

Currently we are using Dell's KACE technology to push the installer to the local machines. The installer is run as the SYSTEM user meaning it does not and can not have direct access to network shares (relevant later).

The application installation workflow is as follows:

Stop Local Security Services to allow software install

Remove anything mapped to drive letter X

Map network drive X \test\test

TestApp.exe /s

msiexec /i Test.msi /quiet

Start Local Security Services to allow software install

copy shortcut file to desktop

The installation itself has 1 Executable and 1 MSI that have to be run. The EXE installs a mainframe application. The MSI file installs a few files locally and then registers 6 DLL files located on that mapped drive.

This is where the issue comes in - Because those files MUST be on that share drive and the installer is running as SYSTEM -> The System account account can't access the mapped drive to register the files so the installation fails.

I am further limited by the fact that I can't simply store a username/password in plaintext in the batch file.

Here is my code so far:

```
REM Stopping McAfee Services
echo Stopping McAfee Services.
net stop mcshield
net stop mcafeeframework

REM Map Network Drive
echo Mapping Network Drive
net use X: /delete /y
net use X: \\test\test

(Here is where I need help - Is there a way to force a username/password prompt here for the user? I basically just want the user to authenticate to the X drive mapping, which will allow the installation to move forward)

echo Starting Test 1 Installation
Test1.exe /s /v"/qb"
echo Starting Test 2 Installation
msiexec /i Test2.msi /quiet
(If the drive has not been mapped by this point, the installation fails as the SYSTEM account can't access the drive)

echo.

REM Restarting Mcafee Services
echo Starting McAfee Services.
net start mcshield
net start mcafeeframework
echo.

REM Copy Shortcut
xcopy "shortcut\*" "C:\Users\public\desktop"
```

Alternatively,

Could/should I convert this to a PS script? I know PS is more powerful than batch, but wasn't sure how to go about it.

Comment: In Powershell you could certainly use the `New-PSDrive` with the `-credential` parameter to map the drive. However, if this is to be unattended that wouldn't get round keeping the credentials in plain text somewhere. Is it not possible to run the whole thing under a different account?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. We are limited to either running the script as SYSTEM user w/ no access to share drive or as the user but the user does not have administrator rights to run the installation. In our current environment it is not possible to elevate the user to administrator. On a side note: While I was working on converting this to a powershell script I found that New-PSDrive parameters such as -credential and -persist were not working (I was getting invalid parameter errors in PS).

Comment: Apart from the X drive being network and unavailable to the system account, I can't see how an app would work anyway. Drive letters are mapped in the user profile context (not the entire system) so if you register files on that drive under some account they will not be visible to another account.  Maybe each user accesses it via a share name not a drive letter?  Group Policy is a common solution for your scenario, and avoids the issue by running credentials that can be elevated for the instal if necessary.

Comment: The application itself is installed on the the server "X". A workstation installer is also run on local clients as there are a few files that HAVE to be installed locally. The vendor designed the installer to point to the X drive when registering the DLLs. Not sure if that answers your question. I don't think a GPO would solve anything in this matter: The fact is we either need 1 of 2 things: Either we need access to the share drive from the SYSTEM account - the only way I know of being that the the share be mapped using a valid user's credentials in that same installation instance.

Comment: OR The installer be run as user and the user be given local admin privs - which doesn't exactly work.

Answer (score 0):

If by forcing authentication prompt, you mean something that will need human input (and you aren't running this script remotely), then this line should interact with existing login session and ask for credentials:

```
start explorer \\test\test
echo After you have entered network credentials
pause
```

Once user enters valid ones, the remaining script can continue

```
net use X: \\test\test
```

Comment: so, I'm not really sure that explorer \\test\test is actually doing anything different than the original script. In fact, I can't see it doing anything at all. Between my line that deletes any existing connection and my net use X: line now there is just a massive pause where nothing seems to be happening for 45 seconds or so, then it just moves on. The Net Use does bring up a prompt in CMD to input username and password, but doesn't loop on invalid creds - I need it to loop until the user inputs creds.

Comment: Now I am unclear on 2 fronts. Is your script being run from an interactive session (i.e. with a login session - UI and all) ? The explorer \\test\test line should have asked for credentials if someone is monitoring the session. If it isn't monitored, please remove that line. Next, do you already know the credentials to \\test\test ? If storing as environment variables is going to work, net use X: \\test\test /user:%network_username% %network_password% will get you the mapping.

Comment: Yes, it's being run from an interactive session - though we want the installation to be as silent as possible. Storing username/password in plain text is not an option. "explorer" did absolutely nothing for me in this script, the script seemed to just ignore that line and move on to the net use. Using net use, I can get CMD to prompt for network ID and password, but there is no validation. If the user enters the wrong ID/Password, the installation just fails. We need the credentials part to loop until successful authentication.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I just edited my answer to include a "start" keyword prior to the explorer line.

Comment: Okay, so I gave this a shot and that sort of worked. When I run start explorer \\test\test under my network account - it works perfectly. However, when I run from local admin/system account - I am neither prompted for credentials nor do I get an immediate response. Instead after about 1-2 minutes of waiting "My Documents" opens. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

After toying with ideas about this problem for a couple of weeks I decided to take a new approach.

I created a new batch file using a simple NET USE and passed the credentials of a service account w/ access to the network share in plain text. Next, I compiled the batch into an executable. It's not the most elegant solution out there I'm sure, but it's sufficient for our needs currently.

Thanks for the help everyone!